# nginx forward single path to http

Tags: ssl, nginx, port, forward, nginx-location

following situation:
I have an play framework server running on localhost:9000. If someone now acces from outside on that server via http, nginx redirect the http request to localhost:9000.

Now i run seperate on that server a rshiny server, that listen on port 9271(https), and has to redirect the traffic to 9270(http).

I tried already some stuff, this one is the last version, that i dont get to work:

```
server {
    listen 9271;
    server_name _;

    ssl    on;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.key;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log xxx_host;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass          http://localhost:9270;
        proxy_read_timeout  90;

        proxy_redirect      http://localhost:9270/ $scheme://$host/;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your configuration. In what way does it not work? What are the entries in `/var/log/nginx/access.log` and `/var/log/nginx/error.log`?

Comment: the access log is fine, the error.log : `2017/05/22 08:07:24 [error] 22226#22226: *16025 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ::ffff:215.58.157.10, server: , request: "GET /shiny:9271 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/shiny:9271", host: "xxx.de"
`

Comment: The error suggests that the problem is with `localhost:9270` and not `nginx`. Is the service running and can you see a service listening on port 9270?